# How To Update App From Different Xcode Project and Computer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, app-store

I have a 2.0 version of an iPhone app that I want to submit an update for.  The first version was built by someone else on their computer.  I started from scratch and built a 2.0 version and am ready to submit it as an update.  I have access to their iOS provisioning profile and everything but not sure exactly what provisioning stuff I need to download.  And do I have to use their old App ID and Bundle ID etC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update an existing app in the iOS App store, it needs to have the exact same bundle ID, a higher version number, and be submitted by the same enrolled iOS Developer account to iTunes Connect.  You can (revoke if necessary and) create a new Distribution certificate and profiles in the iOS Developer Portal, if you don't have the old ones (and their associated private key), and use those for building the update. The provisioning profile you use needs to be suitable for the app's bundle ID (either a matching or wildcard App ID).

Comment: So I created a new user account on my computer, downloaded the proving profiles on their dev account, and created a new certificate from that account and linked it with the dev generated certificate.  I also got the bundle ID from the original app and changed my 2.0 version to that ID.  Should I be good to go?

Comment: in xcode3, in the organizer window is a "Validate" button that will let you check certification and bundleID after you have done the build&archive step. Not sure if and where this is in xcode4, though